# Difference between -> and . in a struct?

Tags: c, struct

If I have a struct like

```
struct account {
   int account_number;
};
```

Then what's the difference between doing

```
myAccount.account_number;
```

and

```
myAccount->account_number;
```

or isn't there a difference?

If there's no difference, why wouldn't you just use the `.` notation rather than `->`? `->` seems so messy.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

-> is a shorthand for `(*x).field`, where `x` is a pointer to a variable of type `struct account`, and `field` is a field in the struct, such as `account_number`.

If you have a pointer to a struct, then saying

```
accountp->account_number;
```

is much more concise than

```
(*accountp).account_number;
```

Answer (score 28):

You use `.` when you're dealing with variables. You use `->` when you are dealing with pointers.

For example:

```
struct account {
   int account_number;
};
```

Declare a new variable of type `struct account`:

```
struct account s;
...
// initializing the variable
s.account_number = 1;
```

Declare `a` as a pointer to `struct account`:

```
struct account *a;
...
// initializing the variable
a = &some_account;  // point the pointer to some_account
a->account_number = 1; // modifying the value of account_number
```

Using `a->account_number = 1;` is an alternate syntax for `(*a).account_number = 1;`

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 9):

You use the different notation according to whether the left-hand side is a object or a pointer.

```
// correct:
struct account myAccount;
myAccount.account_number;

// also correct:
struct account* pMyAccount;
pMyAccount->account_number;

// also, also correct
(*pMyAccount).account_number;

// incorrect:
myAccount->account_number;
pMyAccount.account_number;
```

Answer (score 3):

-> is a pointer dereference and . accessor combined

Answer (score 3):

If `myAccount` is a pointer, use this syntax:

```
myAccount->account_number;
```

If it's not, use this one instead:

```
myAccount.account_number;
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use **struct membrs** both the ways...

one is with DOt:(" **.** ")

```
myAccount.account_number;
```

anotherone is:(" **->** ")

```
(&myAccount)->account_number;
```

Comment: You  don't need `(&` and `)` when using `->`.

Answer (score 0):

`printf("Book title: %s\n", book->subject);
printf("Book code: %d\n", (*book).book_code);`

Comment: You should explain your answer.