# Basic struct question C

Tags: c, struct

for example:

```
typedef struct {  
    int num;  
    int den;  
} rational_number;
```

rational_number `a`;

What is the difference between using
`a.num` or `a.den`
and
`a->num` or `a->den`

Thx in advance.

Comment: Have you tried both? What happens?

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998599/difference-between-and-in-a-struct

Answer (score 5):

`->` is for accessing the members of a pointer to a struct, whereas `.` is for accessing members of the struct itself. `a->num` is really just shorthand for `(*a).num`. Example:

```
typedef struct {  
    int num;  
    int den;  
} rational_number;

rational_number a;
r.num = 1;
rational_number *a_ptr = &a;
a_ptr->num = 2; /* a.num is now 2 */
```

Answer (score 0):

you use a.num, when it is normal variable, and a->num when it is pointer

For ex.

```
rational_number a;
a.num; // is correct
a->num; // is wrong

rational_number *b;

b.num;// wrong
b->num; //is correct
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that in the first case you access the structure via a stack variable:

```
rational_number a;
a.num = 1;
a.den = 1;
```

in the second case via a heap pointer:

```
rational_number* a = new rational_number();
a->num = 1;
a->den = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If a were declared as a pointer to your structure, a->num would return the value of num.

```
rational_number *a;
a->num = 5;
int new_a;
new_a = a->num;
```

You have a is declared as a structure, so you should use a.num to return the value of num.

```
rational_number a;
a.num = 5;
int new_a;
new_a = a.num;
```

Both set the value of new_a to 5.

Also, you can get the address of a if it is a structure and use it like a pointer.

```
rational_number a;
(&a)->num = 5;
int new_a;
new_a = a.num;
```